# Use a new variable to CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, case-when

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    the_debt_id varchar(6) NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_amount int NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_date date NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ('LMUS01', '180', '12/2/2019'), 
       ('LMUS01', '200', '11/2/2019'), 
       ('LMUS01', '300', '13/2/2019'), 
       ('LMUS02', '100', '10/2/2019'), 
       ('LMUS02', '150', '12/2/2019')
```

And I want to create a variable named debt_taxed, and then a variable based on debt_taxed when on certain limits to name it as "exceed", "contained" or "rolling:

```
SELECT the_debt_amount * 1.18 as debt_taxed, 
CASE WHEN the_debt_taxed >= 250 THEN 'Exceed' 
WHEN (the_debt_taxed < 250 and the_debt_taxed >= 200) THEN 'contained' 
ELSE 'rolling' 
END AS status 
FROM my_table
```

But I get an error saying that the_debt_taxed doesn't exist.

Please, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are missing the column the_debt_taxed from the table definition. your table only has column the_debt_id , the_debt_amount  and the_debt_date. Alter table and has the_debt_taxed

Comment: Try this: SELECT the_debt_amount * 1.18 as debt_taxed, 
CASE WHEN (the_debt_amount * 1.18) >= 250 THEN 'Exceed' 
WHEN ((the_debt_amount * 1.18) < 250 and (the_debt_amount * 1.18) >= 200) THEN 'contained' 
ELSE 'rolling' 
END AS status 
FROM my_table

Comment: hello @zip, the_debt_taxed is the column the_debt_amount multiplied by 1.18

Comment: hello @HeikoJakubzik, in this case the WHEN clause is rather long and contains many rules, so I wanted to know if a new variable can be produced to insert easily in the CASE WHEN

Comment: You don't have any variables in your query. Variables are created with a `DECLARE` statement and are prefixed with `@`. What you're actually talking about is a column alias. If you alias a column, other columns in the same query scope won't know what the alias refers to. You would need to use a CTE or a table expression and define `debt_taxed` and then use the CTE or table expression to reference `debt_taxed`.

Comment: Hello @digital.aaron, perhaps its because that I see variables as columns that I made an incorrect statement for SQL. In this case, could you help me with such CTE you mention? What would be the code?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the CTE-based query. zip already posted how to do it with a table expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `debt_taxed` in your `CASE` with the actual calculation.

```
SELECT
    debt_taxed = the_debt_amount * 1.18
    ,status = CASE
                  WHEN the_debt_amount * 1.18 >= 250 THEN 'Exceed'
                  WHEN
                  (
                      the_debt_amount * 1.18 < 250
                      AND the_debt_amount * 1.18 >= 200
                  ) THEN 'contained'
                  ELSE 'rolling'
              END
FROM my_table;
```

If you wanted to use a CTE (common table expression), you'd do something like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        debt_taxed = m.the_debt_amount * 1.18
        ,m.the_debt_id
        ,m.the_debt_date
    FROM my_table m
)
SELECT 
    c.debt_taxed
    ,c.the_debt_id
    ,c.the_debt_date
    ,status = CASE
                  WHEN c.debt_taxed >= 250 THEN 'Exceed'
                  WHEN
                  (
                      c.debt_taxed < 250
                      AND c.debt_taxed >= 200
                  ) THEN 'contained'
                  ELSE 'rolling'
              END
FROM CTE c;
```

Comment: Hello @digital.aaron I see the answer is good, but the last part is not necessary to multiply again by 1.18. Anyway, it leads me to what I needed, that is no to write the formula every time in the CASE clause. Thank you.

Comment: @Manu oops, you're right. That's what I get for copy and pasting. I have corrected the CTE query.

Answer (score 2):

Do this with a sub query:
Replace the table my_table with a table containing a column the_debt_amount * 1.18 named debt_taxed

```
SELECT debt_taxed, 
CASE WHEN the_debt_taxed >= 250 THEN 'Exceed' 
WHEN (the_debt_taxed < 250 and the_debt_taxed >= 200) THEN 'contained' 
ELSE 'rolling' 
END AS status 
FROM (SELECT *, the_debt_amount * 1.18 as debt_taxed from my_table) a
```